# Is it possible to stub a method in a parent class so that all subclass instances are stubbed in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-mocha

Given a parent class `Fruit` and its subclasses `Apple` and `Banana`, is it possible to stub the method `foo` defined in `Fruit`, so that any calls to method `foo` on any instances of `Apple` and `Banana` are stubbed?

```
class Fruit
  def foo
    puts "some magic in Fruit"
  end
end
class Banana < Fruit
  ...
end
class Apple < Fruit
 ...
end
```

`Fruit.any_instance.stubs(:foo)` did not work and it looks like it only stubs for instances of Fruit. Is there a simple way to achieve this other than calling stubs for every subclasses?

Found this link raising the similar question but it looks like it has not been answered yet.
http://groups.google.com/group/mocha-developer/browse_thread/thread/99981af7c86dad5e

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This probably isn't the cleanest solution but it works:

```
Fruit.subclasses.each{|c| c.any_instance.stubs(:foo)}
```

Comment: Yes, it works for this simple example. But it would be a bit clumsy if there are many sub classes. Also it does not work on ActiveRecord models, because the method is [overridden in base.rb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195531/listing-subclasses-doesnt-work-in-ruby-script-console). I was actually looking for a way to stub a method for all controllers and models.

Comment: This method worked well for me, except using `c.constantize.any_instance.stubs(:foo)`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** of *@weexpectedTHIS* answer for Rspec 3.6:

```
 Fruit.subclasses.each do |klass|
    allow_any_instance_of(klass).to receive(:foo).and_return(<return_value>)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If your subclasses have subclasses, you may have to traverse them all recursively. I did something like this:

```
def stub_subclasses(clazz)
  clazz.any_instance.stubs(:foo).returns(false)
  clazz.subclasses.each do |c|
    stub_subclasses(c)
  end
end
stub_subclasses(Fruit)
```